# How do you take all of the same thing from your inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you take all of the same thing from your inventory? I see so many people do it, but I can't seem to figure out the right keys.

Answer (score 2):

To "grab" all of the items of a single type, double click the item